# How do I use 'wildignore' in Vim?

Tags: vim

I'm having a lot of trouble figuring out the syntax for  the `wildignore` setting in Vim.

Suppose I want my file finder plugin (I use [Ctrlp](http://kien.github.com/ctrlp.vim/), which uses `wildignore`) to not search through hidden files and folders, that is, files and folders prefixed with a `.`.

How would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 10):

Concerning `ctrlp.vim` and `wildignore` specifically, if you type `:help ctrlp-options` and read a bit, you will find:

> Note #1: by default, **wildignore** and **g:ctrlp_custom_ignore** only
>   apply when **globpath()** is used to scan for files, thus these options
>   do not apply when a command defined with **g:ctrlp_user_command** is
>   being used.

Thus, you may need to `unlet g:ctrlp_user_command` (possibly set to a default command) to actually use `wildignore`. For instance, in your `~/.vimrc`, add:

```
if exists("g:ctrl_user_command")
    unlet g:ctrlp_user_command
endif
set wildignore+=.*
```

Comment: I had tried adding wildignore, custom_ignore and the ctrl_user_command was not set.  Finally found the another answer @BenC  provided on a  similar question.  The Ctrlp caches results so once you've found files you want to ignore they will still show regardless of what you put in the wildignore/custom ignore until the ctrlp cache is cleared.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21017857/ctrlp-still-searches-the-ignored-directory

Answer (score 10):

As BenC pointed out, Wildignore may not be the best way to ignore files if you are using CtrlP with an external search tool. Instead, you can use CtrlP's "custom_ignore" directive, as stated in their docs:

```
let g:ctrlp_custom_ignore = '\v[\/]\.(git|hg|svn)$'
let g:ctrlp_custom_ignore = {
    \ 'dir':  '\v[\/]\.(git|hg|svn)$',
    \ 'file': '\v\.(exe|so|dll)$',
    \ 'link': 'SOME_BAD_SYMBOLIC_LINKS',
    \ }
```

Comment: How do I separate multiple file patterns?

Comment: @nn0p What do you mean? The extensions are seperated

Comment: Is it possible to do this on a per-directory basis?

Answer (score 8):

Because the title doesn't correspond to the best answer her is mine which corersponds not to ctrlp but to wildignore. Based on 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/579886/1170940

Vim will ignore file patterns specified in option wildignore , so you can set them like so:

```
:set wildignore=*.o,*~,*.pyc
```

For example, my wildignore looks as such

```
 set wildignore+=*/node_modules/*,_site,*/__pycache__/,*/venv/*,*/target/*,*/.vim$,\~$,*/.log,*/.aux,*/.cls,*/.aux,*/.bbl,*/.blg,*/.fls,*/.fdb*/,*/.toc,*/.out,*/.glo,*/.log,*/.ist,*/.fdb_latexmk
```

I use it for both ctrlp and NERDTree

Answer (score 5):

See `:help file-pattern`. Basically if you just want to exclude anything that starts with a dot you can do `.*`.

Comment: Nevermind i figured it out, thanks for the info. Type set:wildignore+=/home/USERNAME/.*

Comment: @Fawkes5:  You can also try `:set wildignore+=.*`.