# ctrlp still searches the ignored directory

Tags: vim, ctrlp

I tried to put ignored setting in .vimrc

But when I used the `ctrlp` to search under rails app folder

It still search the `vendor` folder, so it took lots of time.

But when the search was done, I couldn't search anything under the `vendor`

It was so strange! How to fix it.

Here is my [.vimrc](https://gist.github.com/poc7667/8345685) setting file.

http://d.pr/i/yMtK
http://d.pr/i/Hy4u

```
" Sane Ignore For ctrlp
let g:ctrlp_custom_ignore = {
  \ 'dir':  '\.git$|vendor\|\.hg$\|\.svn$\|\.yardoc\|public\/images\|public\/system\|data\|log\|tmp$',
  \ 'file': '\.exe$\|\.so$\|\.dat$'
  \ }
```

When I appended the code in the end of `.vimrc`

```
217 let g:NERDTreeIgnore=['\~$', 'vendor']
218 set wildignore+=*\\vendor\\**
```

It worked when my first time to use the CTRLP to search under the RAILS app folder,
But still `NOT` worked in the following times.

I guess maybe there are some settings will disable the ignored setting ？

Here are the structure of my folder

```
.
├── Gemfile
├── Gemfile.lock
├── README.rdoc
├── Rakefile
├── app
│   ├── assets
│   ├── controllers
│   ├── helpers
│   ├── mailers
│   ├── models
│   ├── uploaders
│   ├── views
│   └── workers
├── auto.sh
├── config
│   ├── application.rb
│   ├── application.yml
│   ├── boot.rb
│   ├── database.yml
│   ├── environment.rb
│   ├── environments
│   ├── initializers
│   ├── locales
│   ├── macbookair_whenever_schedule.rb
│   ├── menu_navigation.rb
│   ├── navigation.rb
│   ├── resque.god
│   ├── resque_schedule.yml
│   ├── routes.rb
│   ├── schedule.rb -> ubuntu_whenever_schedule.rb
│   ├── tinymce.yml
│   └── ubuntu_whenever_schedule.rb
├── config.ru
├── db
│   ├── development.sqlite3
│   ├── migrate
│   ├── migrate_should_be_skip
│   ├── production.sqlite3
│   ├── schema.rb
│   └── seeds.rb
├── doc
│   └── README_FOR_APP
├── lib
│   ├── assets
│   ├── auto_tools
│   ├── tasks
│   └── url_automation_module.rb
├── log
│   ├── apalog
│   ├── development.log
│   ├── passenger.80.log
│   ├── production.log
│   └── prodution.log
├── output_name
├── public
│   ├── 404.html
│   ├── 422.html
│   ├── 500.html
│   ├── exports
│   ├── favicon.ico
│   ├── results.zip
│   ├── robots.txt
│   ├── sandbox
│   └── uploads
├── script
│   ├── delayed_job
│   └── rails
├── test
│   ├── fixtures
│   ├── functional
│   ├── integration
│   ├── performance
│   ├── test_helper.rb
│   └── unit
├── test.sh
├── tmp
│   ├── cache
│   ├── pids
│   ├── restart.txt
│   ├── sessions
│   └── sockets
├── tmplog
└── vendor
    └── bundle
```

Comment: I don't see `vendor` in your dir ignore list......

Comment: Are you using a plugin that pays attention to `g:ctrlp_custom_ignore`?  In plain vim, setting such a global variable will not have any effect.

Comment: could you give the output of `tree` or `find .` in the directory you're calling vim inside? We don't know how your folders and file setup look like, and that would be helpful for us to get an idea. Ideally, you would give us the full output here: https://asciinema.org/

Answer (score 30):

If you type `:help ctrlp-options` and read a bit, you will find:

> Note #1: by default, **wildignore** and **g:ctrlp_custom_ignore** only
>   apply when **globpath()** is used to scan for files, thus these options
>   do not apply when a command defined with **g:ctrlp_user_command** is
>   being used.

Thus, you may need to `unlet g:ctrlp_user_command` (possibly set to a default command) to actually use `wildignore` as advised by @TomCammann. For instance, in your `~/.vimrc`, add:

```
if exists("g:ctrlp_user_command")
  unlet g:ctrlp_user_command
endif
set wildignore+=*\\vendor\\**
```

After that, you need to refresh your `ctrlp` cache: in Vim, press <kbd>F5</kbd> in `ctrlp` mode, or run `:CtrlPClearAllCaches`, or remove the cache directory directly in your shell:

```
rm -r ~/.cache/ctrlp/      # On Linux
```

Comment: Adding that gives me ```E108: No such variable: "g:ctrlp_user_command"```

Comment: @IanVaughan: is your `ctrlp` plugin up-to-date? This was set to a default value in my case, but if it's not, a guard needs to be added. Check my updated answer.

Comment: Clearing the cache is important if you have already found files you want to exclude and are trying to exclude them subsequently.

Answer (score 21):

part of my .vimrc file . perhaps it will help

```
  set wildignore+=*/.git/*,*/.hg/*,*/.svn/*,*/.idea/*,*/.DS_Store,*/vendor
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `wildignore` vim setting which CtrlP will pick up on.

```
set wildignore+=*\\vendor\\**
```

Comment: hi your setting only worked at the first time I ran `CtrlP`, And not worked in the following times. I have no idea, it must my problems.

Answer (score 5):

Check if you are using some specific search command, like:

```
let g:ctrlp_user_command = 'find %s -type f'        " MacOSX/Linux
let g:ctrlp_user_command = 'dir %s /-n /b /s /a-d'  " Windows
```

This kind of configuration ignores the `g:ctrlp_custom_ignore` option.

Answer (score 0):

`wildignore` may be used by other commands, the reason of failure for `g:ctrlp_custom_ignore` is `g:ctrlp_user_command`, for example, here is mine:

```
if executable('rg')
    let g:ctrlp_user_command = 'rg %s --files --hidden --color=never --glob ""'
endif
```

For this case, rg has own ignore way, just put `.git` to `.gitignore`, rg will not search any files in `.gitignore`.