# In CtrlP, how to set the `mru` mode as the default mode?

Tags: vim, ctrlp

The CtrlP's default file mode is too slow when I open CtrlP in the root of my $HOME dir. it is due to that there are too much files and dirs in my home dir.

I have speeded up the scanning according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22784889/3824053) by using `ag` command instead. However, the scan speed is still slow.

So, I want to set the MRU mode as the default mode of CtrlP. How to do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I agree with @romainl's answer, however for the sake of answering the question :

From `:help CtrlP`

```
                                                            *'g:ctrlp_map'*
 Use this option to change the mapping to invoke CtrlP in |Normal| mode: >
 let g:ctrlp_map = '<c-p>'
                                                           *'g:ctrlp_cmd'*
Set the default opening command to use when pressing the above mapping: >
 let g:ctrlp_cmd = 'CtrlP'
```

Put in your vimrc :

```
let g:ctrlp_map='<c-p>'
let g:ctrlp_cmd = 'CtrlPMRU'
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't start Vim, and don't use a fuzzy finder, in your `$HOME`. It's a pretty stupid idea to begin with and no amount of `ag`-based customization will make it better.

   There's only one useful way to start Vim: navigate to your project and run Vim there.
2. Use the `:CtrlPMRU` command instead of `:CtrlP`.