# ctrlp custom ignore not working as expected

Tags: vim, ctrlp

I have a super simple entry for `ctrlp_custom_ignore` in my `.vimrc`:

```
let g:ctrlp_custom_ignore = 'doc'
```

However, it's not working. Files inside `doc` still show up in my searches. How can I fix this?

Comment: I think this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23015387/2571881) can be useful

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I had a `ctrlp_user_command` which was taking precedence over `ctrlp_custom_ignore`. Rather than getting my `ctrlp_custom_ignore` to work, I just changed the command I had under `ctrlp_user_command` to exclude the directory I wanted excluded.