# How to let CtrlP (vim plugin) ignore pdf files?

Tags: vim, ctrlp

I am working under ubuntu on a latex document in vim and want to use the [CtrlP-Plugin](https://github.com/ctrlpvim/ctrlp.vim) to open different files quickly.

When I press `<c-p>` the small window opens as expected but showing the generated `thesis.pdf` file as a first hit before the `thesis.tex` file which I actually want to edit.

This are the settings in my `.vimrc` (from the [ctrlp-repo](https://github.com/ctrlpvim/ctrlp.vim#basic-options)):

```
let g:ctrlp_map = '<c-p>' 

let g:ctrlp_custom_ignore = {
  \ 'dir':  '\v[\/]\.(git|hg|svn)$',
  \ 'file': '\v\.(exe|so|dll|pdf)$',
  \ }
```

How can I let CtrlP *not* show `.pdf`-files in the matches list (Because it makes no sense for me to open them in vim). What do I need?

Comment: From the documentation: [link] https://github.com/ctrlpvim/ctrlp.vim

`set wildignore+=*.pdf`

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't work unfortunately. Are there any other vim settings likely to interfere with `wildignore`?

Comment: I did find this [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11978291/how-do-i-use-wildignore-in-vim  which may help

Answer (score 0):

Yesterday I edited my .gitignore file and voilà, my beloved ctrl-p recognized this change, avoiding to show the extensions I added to gitignore file